# fileSystem.root.getDirectory and fileSystem.root.getFile threw java.net.MalformedURLException: No installed handlers for this URL

Tags: android, file, cordova, exception

PhoneGap 3.3 file plugin not working with me on Android, i tried getFile and getDirectory, and keep giving me Exception

```
02-20 12:24:34.997: W/System.err(32109): java.net.MalformedURLException: No installed handlers for this URL
02-20 12:24:34.997: W/System.err(32109):    at org.apache.cordova.file.FileUtils.getFile(FileUtils.java:684)
02-20 12:24:35.007: W/System.err(32109):    at org.apache.cordova.file.FileUtils.access$5(FileUtils.java:679)
02-20 12:24:35.007: W/System.err(32109):    at org.apache.cordova.file.FileUtils$16.run(FileUtils.java:349)
02-20 12:24:35.017: W/System.err(32109):    at org.apache.cordova.file.FileUtils$24.run(FileUtils.java:473)
02-20 12:24:35.017: W/System.err(32109):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
02-20 12:24:35.017: W/System.err(32109):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
02-20 12:24:35.017: W/System.err(32109):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

JavaScript Code

```
downloadAgendaPage = function () {
    window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, gotFS, fail);
}

function gotFS(fileSystem) {
    console.log("Emaish: FileSystem Requested");
    console.log("Emaish: fileStream.name = " + fileSystem.name);
    console.log("Emaish: fileStream.root.name = " + fileSystem.root.name);
    fileSystem.root.getFile("text.txt", {create: true, exclusive: false}, gotFileEntry, fail);
}

function gotFileEntry(fileEntry) {
    console.log("Emaish: File Gotten");
    var uri = encodeURI("http://****/data/MYOEB2013_Agenda.ics");
    console.log("Emaish: uri:" + uri);
    var sPath = fileEntry.fullPath.replace("text.txt", "Agenda.ics");
    console.log("Emaish: sPath:" + sPath);
    fileEntry.remove();
    var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();
    fileTransfer.download(
        uri,
        sPath,
        function (theFile) {
            console.log("download complete: " + theFile.toURI());
            //showLink(theFile.toURI());
            alertify.alert("Agenda downloaded to " + theFile.toURI());
        },
        function (error) {
            console.log("download error source " + error.source);
            console.log("download error target " + error.target);
            console.log("upload error code: " + error.code);
        }
    );
}
```

Console.log Result

```
02-20 16:15:37.205: I/chromium(23491): [INFO:CONSOLE(59)] "Emaish: FileSystem Requested", source: file:///android_asset/www/js/agenda.js (59)
02-20 16:15:37.205: I/chromium(23491): [INFO:CONSOLE(60)] "Emaish: fileStream.name = persistent", source: file:///android_asset/www/js/agenda.js (60)
02-20 16:15:37.205: I/chromium(23491): [INFO:CONSOLE(61)] "Emaish: fileStream.root.name = ", source: file:///android_asset/www/js/agenda.js (61)
```

Comment: Can you provide more information please? What are you passing in as a parmater?

Comment: i updated the question to show the javascript Code

Comment: Log Result
02-20 16:15:37.205: I/chromium(23491): [INFO:CONSOLE(59)] "Emaish: FileSystem Requested", source: file:///android_asset/www/js/agenda.js (59)
02-20 16:15:37.205: I/chromium(23491): [INFO:CONSOLE(60)] "Emaish: fileStream.name = persistent", source: file:///android_asset/www/js/agenda.js (60)
02-20 16:15:37.205: I/chromium(23491): [INFO:CONSOLE(61)] "Emaish: fileStream.root.name = ", source: file:///android_asset/www/js/agenda.js (61)

Comment: Hmm odd - seems sane. I would recommend opening org.apache.cordova.file.FileUtils and debugging the line it says it crashes on. At least that way you can tell which path it's trying to resolve, and possibly why the error is happening.

Comment: values are: baseURLstr = "/" , path = "text.txt"
after executing inputURL = new LocalFilesystemURL(baseURLstr);
the result: inputURL.filesystemName is null and also inputURL.fullPath is null

Comment: to know it was working before upgrading from PhoneGap ver phonegap-2.9.1 to ver 3.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for this strange error is that i was manually updating the cordova-plugins.js file and manually adding the plugins js files, because they were n't added automatically.
Why they weren't added automatically? because i was doing it wrong ..

The Answer is don't build then add the plugins, instead add the plugin then build then replace www files with yours.

Answer (score 0):

There is a change in reading the directory structure in phonegap 3.3.0.

I was facing a similar issue where i have to read all the files inside a directory by using fullPath with window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL().

I tried using fileEnteries.fullPath for getting absolute path, but it dint work it was showing  '/'(root) as earlier version it used to be 'file:///'.

**Use entries[i].toURL() to get absoulte path rather than fileEnteries.fullPath **

```
    for (var i = 0; i < entries.length; i++) {

        //Adding into Store for my example          
        data.push({
            fileName : entries[i].name,
            isDirectory : entries[i].isDirectory,
            fullPath : entries[i].toURL() //instead of entries[i].fullPath
        });
    }
```

and later use in **window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(entries[i].toURL() ,success,failuere);**

It worked for me !!

Comment: Thanks for your answer, would u tell me where to call that in my example? as u see in my JS code i use getFile to get the full path, to pass it to the upload function, kindly guide me

Comment: as getFile and getDirectory give exception with me i will not go to the next step to use resolveLocalFileSystemURL

Comment: As i understand ,this issue is due to file "readme.txt" is not available. Why don't you the check the file system once using the Phonegap API [DirectoryReader](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.3.0/cordova_file_file.md.html#DirectoryReader) and make sure you have the file in place .It will give you list of files and directory available under your root directory,if you face any issue you can mail me.