# PhoneGap this.filesystemForURL(inputURL) return null when calling getFile or getDirectory

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins

In PhoneGap 3.3 android application using File-transfer plugin this is the body for getFile method

```
private JSONObject getFile(String baseURLstr, String path, JSONObject options, boolean directory) throws FileExistsException, IOException, TypeMismatchException, EncodingException, JSONException {
        try {
            LocalFilesystemURL inputURL = new LocalFilesystemURL(baseURLstr);
            Filesystem fs = this.filesystemForURL(inputURL);
            if (fs == null) {
                throw new MalformedURLException("No installed handlers for this URL");
            }
            return fs.getFileForLocalURL(inputURL, path, options, directory);

        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            throw new MalformedURLException("Unrecognized filesystem URL");
        }

    }
```

Filesystem fs is always null when calling

```
fileSystem.root.getFile('text.txt', { create: true, exclusive: false }, function (fileEntry) {}, fail);
```

or

```
fileSystem.root.getDirectory('newDir', { create: true, exclusive: false }, function (parent) {}, fail);
```

Here is the javascript Code and the log result

```
downloadAgendaPage = function () {
    window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, gotFS, fail);
}

function gotFS(fileSystem) {
    console.log("Emaish: FileSystem Requested");
    console.log("Emaish: fileStream.name = " + fileSystem.name);
    console.log("Emaish: fileStream.root.name = " + fileSystem.root.name);
    fileSystem.root.getFile("text.txt", {create: true, exclusive: false}, gotFileEntry, fail);
}

function gotFileEntry(fileEntry) {
    console.log("Emaish: File Gotten");
    var uri = encodeURI("http://****/data/MYOEB2013_Agenda.ics");
    console.log("Emaish: uri:" + uri);
    var sPath = fileEntry.fullPath.replace("text.txt", "Agenda.ics");
    console.log("Emaish: sPath:" + sPath);
    fileEntry.remove();
    var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();
    fileTransfer.download(
        uri,
        sPath,
        function (theFile) {
            console.log("download complete: " + theFile.toURI());
            //showLink(theFile.toURI());
            alertify.alert("Agenda downloaded to " + theFile.toURI());
        },
        function (error) {
            console.log("download error source " + error.source);
            console.log("download error target " + error.target);
            console.log("upload error code: " + error.code);
        }
    );
}
```

Console.log Result

```
02-20 16:15:37.205: I/chromium(23491): [INFO:CONSOLE(59)] "Emaish: FileSystem Requested", source: file:///android_asset/www/js/agenda.js (59)
02-20 16:15:37.205: I/chromium(23491): [INFO:CONSOLE(60)] "Emaish: fileStream.name = persistent", source: file:///android_asset/www/js/agenda.js (60)
02-20 16:15:37.205: I/chromium(23491): [INFO:CONSOLE(61)] "Emaish: fileStream.root.name = ", source: file:///android_asset/www/js/agenda.js (61)
```

and therefore threw new MalformedURLException("No installed handlers for this URL");

Comment: add ur fileSystem in console.log and check what it shows

Comment: i updated the question to show the javascript code and console.log result

Comment: to know it was working before upgrading from PhoneGap ver phonegap-2.9.1 to ver 3.3

Comment: check if it is usefull [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21904954/filesystem-root-getdirectory-and-filesystem-root-getfile-threw-java-net-malforme/21952330#21952330). It worked for me

Answer (score 0):

There problem was in the way i add the plugin and build my app, you need to build you application after adding the plugin in order for plugin js files to be copied correctly to the www folder and for cordova_plugins.js to be updated.